# By installing Ubuntu 13.04 on VMWare workstation 9 is running very slow on Host OS Win7

Tags: performance, vmware

I have Core 2 duo PC, 2.1 GHz and with 4GB RAM.

I have Host OS Win7. I have nstalled Workstation 9 on it, and then Ubuntu 13.04 on to workstation 9. The working of Ubuntu 13.04 is very low. How can I enjoy good Ubuntu working with efficient speed?

Thanks Advance.

Comment: What are the specs of the virtual machine?

Comment: How slow is "slow", what are you trying to do in the VM?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you see emulation is sometimes really slow no matter how good your computer is. To get the best preformance you should install Ubuntu like you have windows 7 installed, that would be the best solution  for all.